# Default font style in ttk.Combobox

Tags: python, tkinter

I am using `ttk.Combobox` to build a GUI. I want to know what's the default font name and font size of any text in this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `ttk.Style` and `tkinter.font`.  I don't know if there's a shorter way.

```
import tkinter as tk                                                   
from tkinter import ttk                                                
from tkinter import font

root = tk.Tk()    # font won't work before the Tk object is created

s = ttk.Style()                                    # Create a Style object
combo_font_name = s.lookup( 'TCombobox', 'font' )  # Lookup the name of the default Combobox font

c_font = font.nametofont( combo_font_name )        # Find the font object for that font
c_font.actual()                                    # Dictionary of attributes

# For my PC
# {'family': 'DejaVu Sans',
#  'size': 10,
#  'weight': 'normal',
#  'slant': 'roman',
#  'underline': 0,
#  'overstrike': 0}
```